# How can I transpose these data to obtain something similar to

Tags: python, dataframe, transpose

I got a Dataframe like this:

```
date_of_transaction entity_short_name   tPricestock
4475    3/29/2019   VGF                   2.6
4476    06/07/2019  VGF                   2.6
4477    9/24/2019   VGF                   2.8
4478    11/15/2019  VGF                   2.8
4479    11/21/2019  VGF                   2.8
```

How can I transpose these lists to produce this:

```
            VGF
DATE    
2019-11-25  2.6
2019-11-26  2.6
2019-11-27  2.8
2019-11-28  2.8
2019-11-29  2.8
```

Comment: More information is needed to answer your question. Are the dates in `date_of_transaction` represented as strings or as datetimes? Why do you have only 2019-11-.. in the expected output? What happened to the other months?

Comment: entity_short_name tPricestock
date_of_transaction  
2019-03-29                   VGF 2.6
2019-06-07                  VGF 2.6
2019-09-24                  VGF 2.8
2019-11-15                  VGF 2.8
2019-11-21                  VGF 2.8

Answer (score 0):

making some assumptions, this is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
date_of_transaction = ['3/29/2019','06/07/2019','9/24/2019','11/15/2019','11/15/2019','11/15/2019']
a = pd.DataFrame(date_of_transaction, columns = ['date_of_transaction'])
a['entity_short_name'] = ['VGF','VGF','VGF','VGF','OTHER','OTHER']
a['tPricestock']       = [2.6,2.6,2.6,2.6,2.6,2.6]

#select the rows
VGF = a[a['entity_short_name']=='VGF']

#split data in month,day,year
VGF[['MM','DD','YYYY']] = VGF.date_of_transaction.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(str(x).split("/"))) 

#formata D to DD
for i in range(len(VGF['MM'])):
    if len((VGF['MM'].iloc[i])) <2:
        VGF['MM'].iloc[i] = '0'+VGF['MM'].iloc[i]

#format date the way you want        
VGF['DATE'] = VGF['YYYY']+'-'+VGF['MM']+'-'+VGF['DD']
VGF['VGF']  = VGF['tPricestock']
VGF = VGF[['DATE','VGF']]
```

the output is:

```
Out[58]: 
         DATE  VGF
0  2019-03-29  2.6
1  2019-06-07  2.6
2  2019-09-24  2.6
3  2019-11-15  2.6
```